# download file from server side using angularjs but file format are changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, github

I've created a GET api that interacts with a server and downloads a file automatically, But I am facing many problems when downloading a file. My downloaded files are in an unreadable format. Please give me a suggestion.

```
   this.sendGETRequestFiLeDownload = function(url) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
                       $http.get(url, {
                    headers: {
                         'Accept': "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                         "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "csrfToken": csrfToken,
                        "accessToken": accessToken,
                        "accessValue": accessValue,
                        "accessFlag": accessFlag,
                        "accessVariable": accessVariable,
                        "FAMA-TOKEN": iv,
                        "FAMA-ACCESS-KEY": salt,

                 }
                })
                .then(function(response) { 
                               var data = response.data
                console.log(response);
                    var blob=new Blob([data], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
                    var link=document.createElement('a');
                    link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    link.download="transectionCommisionRepoert.xslx";
                    link.click();
                    defer.resolve(response);
                    },
                    function(errResponse) {
                        self.isSessionAvailable(errResponse);
                        defer.reject(errResponse);
                    }
                );
            return defer.promise;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to Download Binary Files with AngularJS

When downloading binary files, it is important to set the `responseType`:

```
app.service('dataService',['$http',function($http) {

    this.downloadFile = function(url) {

        var config = {      
            //SET responseType
            responseType: 'blob',
            headers: {
                'Accept': "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "csrfToken": csrfToken,
                "accessToken": accessToken,
                "accessValue": accessValue,
                "accessFlag": accessFlag,
                "accessVariable": accessVariable,
                "FAMA-TOKEN": iv,
                "FAMA-ACCESS-KEY": salt,
             }
        };

        return $http.get(url, config);
    } 
]);
```

If the `responseType` is omitted the XHR API defaults to converting [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded text to [DOMString (UTF-16)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) which will corrupt PDF, image, and other binary files.

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - XHR ResponseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use download attribute on a link ? Like that :

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

Comment: i have used but never meet right solution .